# Creating generic redux slice to update nested initialState object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I am working with Redux Toolkit to create generic slice to update nested `initialState` object, but unfortunately because I lack some advanced TS knowledge I cannot find a way how I can achieve that. Here's a code snipped of my another try:

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYygUwIYzQZQDbDJoA0cAChgJ54QYAmAgsjMBAHZwC%20cAZlBCDgByAALo6AVwAeAKwDOAehgQIeANbAYQgFDa0UyLDho2EwQDEAkgFEAMgBEA%20pfuJtcOOYYANOAF5hHgwpIWJ3OAAJAHkAWWt-YQALATQyZLY0UPCAdSiAJQBpBKEAd2g1NPZMsI8AYSiAOQAVBlqm4uR2GAxmLI8opojrPOKIGES0KB1tTl0YSjA0OABxE0nCczQYZEScbuwAHnssDAA%20BIRwuhOALjhj7vDgOVtaOmA2AHM7gCMVPEwbCuJ3swDoljYADcMARrthfv9ATM5gslvY0EEJHgYHssEsApcPNC8BI0HcMGxKHAFAo4NklsgKXAARhIUsKZRSGwxnAMkQ5HIMFAqTxoHBxs84M85KSnnJQbBKAjVEiPM8AGowsHKllAjyTfhQO5yGBQD6fZF6AzQeDzRaeaCCAnhADaVjsThcADp6s1Wk0ALp3QkeOBumwOZz2L3ROJB%204YjBYnH7NDhDzhj1Rr25Qrx9GY7G47DhWYZ92R70DIZ5eMh8sRz3RrzefOJ5PFtMeWazbR2pYQzTAGGdhKrDJm5Cbba7VMHcyO066fSGeCdNgm%207WLwAVVsTWcDTIO4POBaTWsdwLSaLqYu4WJpLuQj6UvlwEVdyCeDkJDlmthO5TVJGpjCgQ1nx0bgMDkFB2BNXQrVXOCN3gD4hxHVM7kHFhMLxe8PDhDBg3TMMKybH1GhaNo61Ihss29WNrHzbcGD3A9LCPE9HDPBgL1A0MyMbbNcwKFjd33Q9j1Pc9rFIzgBKEhjo2rYZaME%20jK2bHxxLYyTOOknjZPk0tQKI0FwShLU4TJcUoBAuVXnoc0vxhX9LX7OAcDQZhWDYAo0EoWCAjUQKIB4B0oBAPtUTgTUoAaDAQDQGIMDAA52n0bA2DoWDvN89gAqC84AgXKKXUDXQaTgSwhDZYwcrQOg4AkMA4BKTREhQdAsD8uBwrgVK2oG38CrYBRoQSpKljADAPzkUhlGZLY4CaVE5FQYAwHgNRuRKcUJjgOg0DQRYoF5NATXNcV1tIH4JHgDrxggB64AwOAZWQfk5C9GL7Xylh2HixLkrkIaCLDIoPi8nzAf8wK5HU0MXQAKSlDhQsoAbgemoaDgKU54xdUa4buApSEmkHbJRgMPBpaxPi9MMSb8u5yOzX1qKaCmhSptnhMY2JmNLF1Mex3ncbS-HCZmF0Ab8orEcQzyKGoN4oh%20GRYYy4wpGy3KYbGnHQaGkrEGpWkmkSSVJRKRIsBqt7BBNezPk%20AgvnazrwhZ9g7iaF0AAYAwfCXkv9l0AEYQ6JGEnzeykLbgR8Zv4M75iOiBLrYIR4BALBsHO0VzolWD9CSsAAXCA1oAAfmNU1zUtddN2LkB8EIfFuswbAO6IAAKEM2Gm5829fdDcLwTtQPECQiCgOQSME1qbIA%20P%205NPFSB6UnyCoGh6CYOGDlVg%206A1rXmAOeWgbDy7TdOABKfxznrUM5CenY4H7ne-K9Wa1b0C9L7Ngz836CUZL%20TwAtoyc39EvDSED4LwEptNBIv92D-33m8L0qDkpJxqvAOQyQsTNR%20EsYe4EIAlCanACY6A4A-CpB-TQX9IEkF1osZgtCXowDAA9fmykYxCzgAAH2gUI0SuhEGCWqmAdAkJWASDkHgKklgjpggOs8O6r11H23qu9HgJ0PafAOlgIQsFuS2kOmaT4iRHpUBuNImRdNaQtxQXfdBY0sGALoLgzxME4BiwimVEAmYtKUT9DRZxLj3H9TwHQNeXdN7YC9ERF0GC2A%20LPsA2GfkAwujwWgAM-iSRLGqtYKh507hkDTpMDOQhwkURbAGIQmdLq8h5PoZ48B2A3XtEIbIZpug-ABPYKAGAeAwAOEgZIyVKgZCvO2W8eIADc7VygLNsteDsqZ1mcFOEIL0MA5D9wAOyBwAKwAGZH4xJkSktAaSTgZO8QAnJICClFNps6FxgkU7kjedgoBKc4C11rvExJcc-x-NDM8BU8wgL2RhbCt8AFtRwAAISZOyTgmuUBFIuPxXcTF2KgW%20K9PisFb1yU5KpZBOiGleywp%20D1NQjLuz3IgTBJY7MqyDGGAg2JyDIVJISI8553RXlw1xUAz50q-7vJwd80ppICGWCISQhJjCKFCn4DQ5q9ClhMI%20p-Lq7DSArlhjwh6-CYCCIiS2LlGkJXpJxUquVeT2AFPdcCvx3yIawoBTSmVHr-XQrBRC1QUKymEpkfCj8iK7IOVRWi6yJLfUUvxXGxBxKsVktDX6ylVTqWZrpSWhlsKyx-NZZgdlLjq2IOOoWe1bgWVso5VwRljau2cs4HcpCNoUKbiQCvPEYruABDbn3J5mS5CDqMM2m88Bp0ECIF6We88gA)

```js
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export enum FIELD_ID {
  FAX = 'fax',
  HOME = 'homePhone',
  WORK = 'workPhone',
  CONTACT = 'contact',
  OTHER = 'other'

}

type GenericFetchState<Data> = {
  data: Data
  isLoading: boolean
  error?: {
    name?: string
    message?: string
    code?: string
    stack?: string
  }
  dataDidInvalidate: boolean
  formId?: string
}

type DefaultState = {
  value: any // We can leave any, not necessary for this issue
  isDirty: boolean
  isValid: boolean
  error: string
}

export type Form = {
  [FIELD_ID.CONTACT]: {
    [FIELD_ID.HOME]: DefaultState
    [FIELD_ID.WORK]: DefaultState
  }
  [FIELD_ID.OTHER]: {
    [FIELD_ID.FAX]: DefaultState
  }
}

type InitialState = GenericFetchState<Form>

export const DEFAULT_INPUT_STATE: DefaultState = {
  value: '',
  isDirty: false,
  isValid: true,
  error: ''
} as const


export const initialState: InitialState = {
  data: {
    [FIELD_ID.CONTACT]: {
      [FIELD_ID.HOME]: DEFAULT_INPUT_STATE,
      [FIELD_ID.WORK]: DEFAULT_INPUT_STATE
    },
    [FIELD_ID.OTHER]: {
      [FIELD_ID.FAX]: DEFAULT_INPUT_STATE
    }
  },
  dataDidInvalidate: true,
  isLoading: false,
  error: null,
  formId: null
}

type SectionKeys = keyof Form
type VarNameMap<T extends SectionKeys> = Form[T]

// I've ended up with creation of Map of section/varName pairs, to let Typescript know the deeper nesting types, but without a success.
type SectionVarNamesMap = {
  [K in SectionKeys]: {
    [J in keyof VarNameMap<K>]: [section: K, varName: J]  //Eg. [section: FIELD_ID.CONTACT, varName: FIELD_ID.HOME]
  }[keyof VarNameMap<K>]
}[SectionKeys]


type PayloadObject<T extends SectionVarNamesMap> = { // This is what I am struggling with
  section: T[0]
  varName: T[1]
  value: any // value property doesn't matter for this example
  error?: string
}

const formSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'form',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    updateValue: (state, action: PayloadAction<PayloadObject<SectionVarNamesMap>>) => {
      switch (action.payload.section) {
        case FIELD_ID.CONTACT: {
          const varName = action.payload.varName //  It should be narrowed here by switch case, expected output: FIELD_ID.HOME | FIELD_ID.WORK

          // previously I did this, but I have a feeling that's not the right way:

          // const varName = action.payload.varName as keyof Form[FIELD_ID.CONTACT]

          const oldValue = state.data[action.payload.section][varName].value // Error : Property '[FIELD_ID.FAX]' does not exist on type 'WritableDraft<{ homePhone: DefaultState; workPhone: DefaultState; }>'.ts(7053)

          state.data[action.payload.section][varName] = {
            value: action.payload.value ?? oldValue,
            isDirty: true,
            isValid: !action.payload.error,
            error: !!action.payload.error ? action.payload.error : ''
          }

          break
        }

        case FIELD_ID.OTHER: {
          const oldValue = state.data[action.payload.section][action.payload.varName].value //  It should be narrowed here by switch case, expected output: FIELD_ID.FAX

          state.data[action.payload.section][action.payload.varName] = {
            value: action.payload.value ?? oldValue,
            isDirty: true,
            isValid: !action.payload.error,
            error: !!action.payload.error ? action.payload.error : ''
          }
          break
        }
        default: {
          break
        }
      }
    }
  }
})

export const { updateValue } = formSlice.actions
export default formSlice.reducer
```

For now I've used `as` keyword inside each switch case to tell TS explicitly what type it should expect, but I feel like it's a wrong way.

Any help is warmly welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually close to the solution, here it is:

```
type SectionVarNamesMap = {
  [K in SectionKeys]: {
    [J in keyof VarNameMap<K>]: [section: K, varName: J]  
  }[keyof VarNameMap<K>]
} // ! Removed [SectionKeys] from here

type PayloadObject<T extends SectionVarNamesMap> = { 
 [K in SectionKeys]: {
  section: T[K][0]
  varName: T[K][1]
  value: any 
  error?: string
 }
}[SectionKeys] // Added [SectionKeys] here
```

[TS Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYygUwIYzQZQDbDJoA0cAChgJ54QYAmAgsjMBAHZwC%20cAZlBCDgByAALo6AVwAeAKwDOAehgQIeANbAYQgFDa0UyLDho2EwQDEAkgFEAMgBEA%20pfuJtcOOYYANOAF5hHgwpIWJ3OAAJAHkAWWt-YQALATQyZLY0UPCAdSiAJQBpBKEAd2g1NPZMsI8AYSiAOQAVBlqm4uR2GAxmLI8opojrPOKIGES0KB1tTl0YSjA0OABxE0nCczQYZEScbuwAHnssDAA%20BIRwuhOALjhj7vDgOVtaOmA2AHM7gCMVPEwbCuJ3swDoljYADcMARrthfv9ATM5gslvY0EEJHgYHssEsApcPNC8BI0HcMGxKHAFAo4NklsgKXAARhIUsKZRSGwxnAMkQ5HIMFAqTxoHBxs84M85KSnnJQbBKAjVEiPM8AGowsHKllAjyTfhQO5yGBQD6fZF6AzQeDzRaeaCCAnhADaVjsThcADp6s1Wk0ALp3QkeOBumwOZz2L3ROJB%204YjBYnH7NDhDzhj1Rr25Qrx9GY7G47DhWYZ92R70DIZ5eMh8sRz3RrzefOJ5PFtMeWazbR2pYQzTAGGdhKrDJm5Cbba7VMHcyO066fSGeCdNgm%207WLwAVVsTWcDTIO4POBaTWsdwLSaLqYu4WJpLuQj6UvlwEVdyCeDkJDlmthO5TVJGpjCgQ1nx0bgMDkFB2BNXQrVXOCN3gD4hxHVM7kHFhMLxe8PDhDBg3TMMKybH1GhaNo61Ihss29WNrHzbcGD3A9LCPE9HDPBgL1A0MyMbbNcwKFjd33Q9j1Pc9rFIzgBKEhjo2rYZaME%20jK2bHxxLYyTOOknjZPk0tQKI0FwShLU4TJcUoBAuVXnoc0vxhX9LX7OAcDQZhWDYAo0EoWCAjUQKIB4B0oBAPtUTgTUoAaDAQDQGIMDAA52n0bA2DoWDvN89gAqC84AgXKKXUDRDPPylh2HixLkrkVKwAIsMig%20LyfNq-zArkdTQxdAApKUOFCyhwrioUGpStKDgKU54xdX8CrYO4ClIaEEqS2zBoDDxSxdMaJvq7bmrmhaZmpWkAEI4DyNAQAgNk6DDGq-KKvreH4QQJnQFF7Qoag3iiH4ZC6jLjCkbLcs6laTsa5qSsQOB3BddqODewrev65buruJo0YDF0AAYAwfKbtvxwmXQARjJokYSfOAORR-VwOgAB%20Y1TXNdwexdTGeqCvaaTgBg6DoNAXoFrr3uxuBfrTbR103UUovwQh8RQdA8Q1ogAAoQzYSnAkdV90NwvBO1A8QJCIKA5BIwSJDAGyAKZ-WTTxUgejx8gqBoegmG6g5AcDugQbB5gDkF%20G0CatLTlOABKfxznrUM5BKTQdjgfXfb8r0wADt4vVxvzU4zwTGV-TxhO9X1qKaJ2NOr%20D4E26aEgL9gi5L%20gvU77a6I0lX4FUOh3a1r3sC9IiXR7tg%206Bgfy-YImh%20SgNB8ZpXW8Eme0Dnk4F5W5fw7L2X15dTe0D251940x9bMX8-S%20fuAOY5uAJ6nxTH%20eAqeYQF7J-kfoJDU1k7jXVfsXFedAvQGmgP-feSCjRwGujAs%20cCL5oM-szbB-cEF4MgiPQSvZwFwB%20DrNQZCuC6EfjXJY5FsyqTyC3Rh7cf54EnrvBIh9j7dFPt1N%20q8r5sCJrAohO8tpbx3iSJYDDwECPnlI%20Bl8VqSMIeo2%20983CUIZgo8k2iL4fy-tw3hCiUGt0AR%20YBdkHIGLfABbUGC1G4PZlAaxGk0HQKwSInBpc8Hf3cUEzxcBSGULLOA6hmBaGP2ia3SWhYYAcP3rEjA8T96JNDDk6JPZk7LmtEYMeyMXZuz4dwAIasQB6yPovOQSEbRwGSTeeANS6leltvbIAA)